# System calls in GAS

Tags: assembly, system-calls, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to create a folder in 64 bit GNU as like this:

```
.global main

.text
main:
    movl $83, %edi      # SYS_mkdir
    movl $folder, %esi  # folder_name
    movl $0777, %edx    # flags
    call syscall

    ret                 # exit
folder: .string "folder"
```

this code works, however I'd rather implement it using the "int 0x80" call, but I can't seem to get it to work, I've tried it like this:

```
mov $83, %eax
mov $folder, %ebx
mov $0777, %ecx
syscall
```

however it does not work, even if I use the 64 bit registers.

Also how could I translate this code to 32 bit? (preferably using int 0x80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In 64 bit syntax you have to use syscall like this:**

```
mov $folder, %rdi
mov $0777, %rsi
mov $83, %rax
syscall
```

**In 32 bit all you have to do is replace registers with 32 bit ones and use `int 0x80` instead of `syscall`**

Comment: _"In 32 bit all you have to do is replace registers with 32 bit ones and use `int 0x80` instead of `syscall`"_. Not really. The system call number is different in 32-bit mode (39 instead of 83), and the arguments go in `ebx` and `ecx`.

Comment: that does not seem to be the case, the 32 bit values seem to have worked on 64 bit also.